# Spring get all with a set of custom object with correct ID

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa

I have a User object, and a Ticket object that have a ManyToMAny relationship

```java
class User{
private Long id;
@ManyToMany
private Set<Ticket> tickets;
}
class Ticket{
@ManyToMany
private Set<User> users;
}
```

Obviously this is a very simplified pseudo-like version of the code, but what would i name the method in my JPA Repository, to get all of the tickets that have a user with the specified ID in it? Is this possible, or should I make a custom query?

Answer (score 1):

You can write 2 different **named queries**:

```java
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Long> {
    List<Ticket> findAllByUsers(User user);
    List<Ticket> findAllByUsersIdIn(List<Long> userIds);
}
```

Method `findAllByUsers(..)` takes **`User object`** to search and return results, method `findAllByUsersIdIn(..)` takes **`user ids`** to search and return results.